# I am linking another page to my navigation tab and it is getting blocked

Tags: wordpress, html

I am placing a link of my another page's permalink which is because it is getting developed in Wordpress to my Navigation tabs.As The tabs are getting clicked it is not referring to any other page as it is staying on the same page.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
      <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
          <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="/brand" role="tab" targe>HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="/brand/aboutus" role="tab">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="/brand/services" role="tab">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item waves-effect waves-light">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="/brand/patient-forms" role="tab">PATIENT FORMS</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Note:It was working fine with normal a href="".

Answer (score 0):

Have you made an htacces change? Might wanna try saying href="/brand.html/" instead. Also, end the link with a /
Also, in your first link to /brand/, you have an unfinished tag "targe", might cause some trouble.